# Paying VAT as a Freelancer - I live in EU, my client is from USA

Tags: taxes, usa, eu, freelance, vat

I am an IT freelancer, living in the NL, and I have EU citizenship. One of my clients is from the US. Do i have any tax/VAT obligations in the states?